# Trying to rename two files in PHP

Tags: php, rename, wowza

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, apache2 + nginx (ISPManager)

My server works with Wowza Media Server, and that server put my recorded `.flv` videos in `{root-of-the-server}/movies`

I recieve the name of video from `$_GET['rfile']` of the action: `$this->request->get('rfile')`.

The file is created in the folder successfully, I locate it in two ways:

```
file_get_contents('http://<ip, which sends to {root-of-the-server}>/movies/'.$this->request->get('rfile'));
```

or

```
`find /movies/ -name $rfile`;
```

To upload my rec videos from the Wowza folder to web-site, I'm trying to rename the file after the recording is stopped:

From
`'{root-of-the-server}/movies/$this->request->get('rfile').flv'`
To
`'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/resume/resume'.$item['id'].'.flv'`

I use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, because I need to move the recorded videos automatically, and on the several websites.

Note: I don't put the `{root-of-the-server}` in my actual script, that's just a placeholder for posting here.

I'm trying to rename this with PHP.
First try:
`shell_exec('mv /movies/'.$this->request->get('rfile').''.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/resume/resume'.$item['id'].'.flv');`
Second try:
`mv /movies/$rfile /movies/ok-just-rename-it-plz.flv`
Third try:
`rename('http://95.183.8.96:81/'.$this->request->get('rfile'), 'http://95.183.8.96:81/'.$item['id'].'.flv');`
Fourth try:
`rename('/movies/'.$this->request->get('rfile'), '/upload/resume/resume'.$item['id'].'.flv');`

However none of these attempts worked. How can I rename these two files with a http wrapper? Or how can I rename them in another way?

Comment: Hi there, I made some edits to your post to try and arrange formatting and made the English clearer.  Please ensure I haven't made mistakes or misunderstood what you were trying to say. One formatting note, you don't need to use `<br>` to do new lines, if you add two spaces at the end of a line that will work too, and makes it easier to write your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem of these days was in `open_basedir` of ISPmanager (`open_basedir` is turned on by default).
I went to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and made these changes:

`<Directory /var/www/USER/data/www/WEBSITE>
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/movies:/var/www/USER/data:."
</Directory>`

instead of

`<Directory /var/www/USER/data/www/WEBSITE>
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/USER/data:."
</Directory>`

Anyway, thanks to Kevin Nagurski for answer :33

Answer (score 1):

`rename` is what you need. If it were possible over HTTP, you'd have a major security hole, so stick to the absolute paths. Make sure your destination directory is writable with PHP:

```
echo is_writable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/resume/resume') ? 'yup' : 'nope';
```

Also check to make sure the source file actually exists:

```
echo file_exists('/movies/' . $this->request->get('rfile')) ? 'yup' : 'nope';
```

And that you have permission to read it:

```
echo is_readable('/movies/' . $this->request->get('rfile')) ? 'yup' : 'nope';
```

If any of these fail, you have a permissions issue that you need to rectify with a bit of `chmod` or `chown`.

Comment: thanks to your advice. "web_site"/upload/resume is writable, but my movies aviable only from http://server_ip:81, and not aviable from 'movies' folder. how can i call the root of entire server, instead of current web server (DOCUMENT_ROOT)?

Comment: @МаксимБуканов root of the entire server is just `/`. So the movies are manually placed in the `/movies/` directory. There are a few options for making this available to PHP, such as ensuring the user placing the files and PHP are in the same group. But the easiest option (not best, easiest) is to give global READ privileges to the directory (`chmod -R a+r /movies`)

Comment: i can't reach the root of the entire server with '/'; return of 'getenv("SERVER_NAME");' is the website, where i am trying launch these operations (but my folder of recorded movies placed in the root of entire server, not of current web server)

Comment: If you log into the server (via SSH) and type `cd /` you'll get to the root of the server, so `cd /movies` will get you to the movies folder in the root of the server (not the Apache web server, but rather the Linux server). If it's in the root of your user's directory, it'll be `cd ~/movies`